# algorithm for the inverse of a 2d bijective function

Tags: algorithm

I want to write a function **f_1(a,b) = (x,y)** that approximates the inverse of f, where **f(x,y) = (a,b)** is a bijective function (over a specific range)

Any suggestions on how to get an efficient numerical approximation?

The programming language used is not important.

Comment: If your function is well behaved, you can approximate the inverse iteratively using a root finding method. Here's some inspiration in the 1-d case http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~jared/Math341/iteration.pdf. Secant method can work (slower) if you don't have access to derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Solving `f(x,y)=(a,b)` for x,y is equivalent to finding the root or minimum of `f(x,y)-(a,b)` ( = 0) so you can use any of the standard root finding or optimization algorithms. If you are implementing this yourself, I recommend [Coordinate descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) because it is probably the most simple algorithm. You could also try [Adaptive coordinate descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_coordinate_descent) although that may be a bit harder to analyze.

If you want to find the inverse over a range, you can either compute the inverse at various points and interpolate with something like a [Cubic Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) or solve the above equation whenever you want to evaluate the inverse function. Even if you solve the equation for each evaluation, it may still be helpful to precompute some values so they can be used as initial values for a solver such as Coordinate descent.

Also see [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and the [Bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'automatic' solution that wil work for any general function. Even in the simpler case of y = f(x) it can be hard to find a suitable starting point. As an example:

```
y = x^2
```

has a nice algebraic inverse

```
x = sqrt(y)
```

but trying to approximate the sqrt function in the range [0..1] with a polynomial (for instance) sucks badly.

If your range is small enough, and your function well behaved enough, then you might get a fit using 2D splines. If this is going to work, then you should try using independant functions for x and y, i.e. use

```
y = Y_1(a,b)  and x = X_1(a,b)
```

rather than the more complicated

```
(x,y) = F_1(a,b)
```